# Select rows with different values on different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL so this took my a long time without being able to figure it out.
My table looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+
|ID    |2016  | 2017 |
+------+------+------+
|1     |A     |A     |
+------+------+------+
|2     |A     |B     |
+------+------+------+
|3     |B     |B     |
+------+------+------+
|4     |B     |C     |
+------+------+------+
```

I would like to have only the rows which have changed from 2016 to 2017:

```
+------+------+------+
|ID    |2016  | 2017 |
+------+------+------+
|2     |A     |B     |
+------+------+------+
|4     |B     |C     |
+------+------+------+
```

Could you please help ?

Comment: This question has a pretty basic SQL solution that is already posted below. However, for clarity, what database client are you using?

Comment: Oracle EssBase.

Comment: Just an FYI – I updated the question to remove the Essbase tag. You probably have Essbase in your environment somewhere, but this is actually the relational database (SQL Server, Oracle relational) side of things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select * from mytable where column_2016<>column_2017`
assuming your column labels are column_2016 and column_2017